# PHP - Read an image with URL

Tags: php, image

Here my problem, I do a query to MySQL (PDO) for give me the last 5 URLs of a table nammed avatar who contains the ID and the URL :

```
$response = $dbh->query("SELECT url FROM avatar ORDER BY id_URL DESC LIMIT 0,5 ");
```

And I did :

```
  while ($donnees = $response->fetch())
{

$urlImage = $donnees['url']; //'url' contains the URL
$result = file_get_contents($urlImage);        
header('Content-Type: image/png');
echo $result;   
?>
```

But the header just return a small empty white square.  However, the "$result = file_get_contents($urlImage);" takes properly the URL because when I do :

```
   $urlImage = $donnees['url']; //'url' contains the URL
$result = file_get_contents($urlImage);        
echo $result;   
?>
```

It just shows the "encodage of the image" (a ton of special characters) but not displays the image.

I also try with "imagick" but it says to me that the class doesn't exist and I don't think that the imagecreatefrompng can be use with URL.

Thanks !

Comment: @Hexadect Where's the decimal?

Comment: @BenM Can you set a LIMIT of 0,5?

Comment: @Hexadect Yes. The first integer is simply the offset. So `LIMIT 10,5` would fetch 5 records, with an offset of 10. `LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0` == `LIMIT 0,5` == `LIMIT 5`.

Comment: @Hexadect Yes, the "LIMIT 0, 5" is here to indicate that the limit is between 0 and 5 but I think it's need to be reversed with the comma. There is an example in W3Schools.

Comment: @Mofallo999 Yes I know. I'm saying that `LIMIT 0,5` is the same as `LIMIT 5`.

Comment: @BenM Sorry, wrong recipient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use a dynamic image source where your url is the image source, and it isn't working, then the problem might be that there's a space or extra character somewhere on the page, which will make the browser treat it like a document instead of an image in some cases.

Your problem is that the browser isn't understanding that it's supposed to be an image.

You could always do:

```
<img src="<?=$urlImage?>">
```

Comment: 1. `<img />` is a self-closing tag. 2. That's the purpose of `header('Content-Type: image/png');`.

Comment: @BenM. I come on and help someone where you couldn't and you give me a downvote?

Comment: @AuntJamaima I downvoted because this doesn't actually solve the problem. Hotlinking to an image inside of `<img />` is not the same objective as the OP posted. They wish to output the image directly from a PHP script; those are two distinct problem sets.

Comment: @BenM. Where does he say he wants to output directly from the script? He's running a while loop and said he tried imagick and couldn't make it display. This is a case of server client confusion. Case in point he already said that this works in his comment above.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this and see if it works?

```
 $image = file_get_contents($donnees['url']);
 $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
 header('content-type: ' . $finfo->buffer($image));
 echo $image;
```

This is suppose to handle one Image. One php script can return one image. If you want to combine the images and render a big long image then probably you should look at http://image.intervention.io/

**EDIT**

What I understood after trying out the above code is that if you put file_get_contents before header then the raw characters are shown. However you put it after header then everything seems to be working

```
$image="http://www.hillspet.com/HillsPetUS/v1/portal/en/us/cat-care/images/HP_PCC_md_0130_cat53.jpg";
$filename = basename($image);
$file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($filename,"."),1));
switch( $file_extension ) {
    case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
    case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
    case "jpeg":
    case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpeg"; break;
    default:
}

header('Content-type: ' . $ctype);
$image = file_get_contents($image);
echo $image;
```

Working [fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8qpe-icz4)

Comment: No, I want to return one image, this is a loop so the variable will always render one image ? 
But that's the same that's my code, it's return meta data of the image.

Comment: You have written the header and echo inside the loop. That means it will echo it 5 times. So even though the client side thinks it is an image but it cannot render it as it is some combination for 5 image urls. Try doing limit 0,1

Comment: Ah, yes I understand what you say, but I make the Limit 0,1 and remove the loop, that's give the same result.

Comment: Hi, I just copy paste your code but this just returns a small empty white square.

Comment: @Mofallo999 please try out the demo.. the picture is coming fine. Also note that your url cannot have https, so replace that with http (if working with http) using $image = str_replace("https", "http", $image); after the first line

Comment: Hi, it still doesn't work, I also put the str_replace but always return me a small empty white square. I Don't understand...